Laravel 11.x Eloquent Way To Get Relation Through Relations (4 Total Tables)
I'm using latest version of Laravel. I'm trying to setup a model method relationship that passes through other intermediary tables.
Understanding the table structure below, my goal is retrieve a collection of Students (only) which are enrolled in a course that belongs to a curriculum model.
Curriculum->Course->Students Course->Student
I've come close, as you can see in the Curriculum model, student() method, I can retrieve a collection of all courses along with their students... but I don't want the courses along with it.
Is there an Eloquent way to accomplish this?
Thank you!
Table Structure
curriculum
id
..
courses
id
curriculum_id
..
students_courses
id
course_id
student_id
..
students
id
..
Models
curriculum
    /**
     * @return HasMany
     */
    public function course(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Course::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return HasManyThrough
     */
    public function class(): HasManyThrough
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(ClassModel::class, Course::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return HasManyThrough
     */
    public function student()
    {
        // this works as expected, but brings courses too, I only want students.
        return $this->hasManyThrough(StudentCourse::class, Course::class)->with('student');
    }

course
    /**
     * @return HasMany
     */
    public function class(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ClassModel::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return BelongsTo
     */
    public function curriculum(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Curriculum::class, 'curriculum_id', 'id');
    }

    /**
     * @return HasManyThrough
     */
    public function student(): HasManyThrough
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Student::class, StudentCourse::class,
            'course_id',
            'id',
            'id',
            'student_id'
        );
    }

students_courses

    /**
     * @return BelongsTo
     */
    public function student(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->BelongsTo(Student::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return BelongsTo
     */
    public function course(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->BelongsTo(Course::class);
    }

student

    /**
     * @return HasOne
     */
    public function user(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->HasOne(User::class, 'userID', 'user_id');
    }

    /**
     * @return HasManyThrough
     */
    public function course(): HasManyThrough
    {
        return $this->HasManyThrough(Course::class, StudentCourse::class,
            'student_id',
            'id',
            'id',
            'course_id'
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return HasManyThrough
     */
    public function class(): HasManyThrough
    {
        return $this->HasManyThrough(ClassModel::class , StudentClass::class,
        'student_id',
        'id',
        'id',
        'class_id'
        );
    }


I don't think you're going to find an entirely Eloquent based solution to your problem. In my experience Eloquent works well with one-to-many (two table) and many-to-many (three table) relationships but beyond that it gets messy.
As you don't want any Course information you might be better off using a Builder query, something like:
class Curriculum extends Model
{
    ...

    public function students()
    {
        return Student::select('students.*')
            ->join('students_courses', 'students.id', '=', 'students_courses.student_id')
            ->join('courses', 'students_courses.course_id', '=', 'courses.id')
            ->where('courses.curriculum_id', $this->id)
            ->distinct()
            ->get();
    }
}

You need the select('students.*') to prevent any other table columns being dragged into the Student models, but at least you end up with just a collection of students.
I recommend putting function like this in a separate custom builder class for your Curriculum model so it keeps the model class cleaner. Have a look at using newEloquentBuilder, there are a number of articles describing how to implement them.

I was hoping this wasn't the case, but this solution works well. And since I'm already using repository classes on top of models, implementing a newEloquentBuilder was surprisingly easy and kept my model clean like you said. Great suggestion, thank you.

Seems you are confusing models with pivots when setting up your relations. StudentCourse is not a model, but a pivot, and for such simple example you don't need to define this class at all.
Students have a direct relationship with courses already, via a belongsToMany relation. And this relationship will make use of student_courses table to resolve the relation.
And for your goal to retrieve a collection of Students (only) which are enrolled in a course that belongs to a curriculum model, you can query relationships however deep you want.
Student::query()
  ->whereHas('courses', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->whereHas('curriculum', function (Builder $query) {
      $query->where('name', $curriculum_name);
    });
  });

rel: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many
query: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations
